# How can I execute OpenSMILE toolkit from Matlab environment?

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, speech, audeering-opensmile

I want to use the OpenSMILE toolkit as a voice feature extractor. But I developed my project scripts in the Matlab environment. So, I am searching for a way to calling OpenSMILE from Matlab and handle the features obtained. I would be pleased if anybody guides me on this matter.

OpenSMILE script sample that can be executed in windows CMD environment:

```
SMILExtract_Release.exe -C config/MFCC.conf -I a.wav -O a.HTK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very simple way to do this. After installing the OpenSMILE, this program can be accessed through the CMD environment. That's why I wrote the following function in MATLAB and ran OpenSMILE through it.

```
function featureSet = OpenSmileFE_MFCC(filePath,fileName)

% make result file name
resultName  = [fileName,'_MFCC.HTK'];

% make OpenSmile Command
comD =['SMILExtract_Release.exe -C config/MFCC12_E_D_A_Z.conf -I ',filePath,... 
'-O ', resultName , '  -noconsoleoutput'];


% excute command
system(comD);
[ features, sampPeriod, parmKind ] = readhtk_lite( resultName );
```

you can also find the **readhtk_lite** function script in [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/32849/versions/3/previews/mfcc/readhtk_lite.m/index.html) link. you can also remove -noconsoleoutput option from the command as below to see the execution detail.

```
comD =['SMILExtract_Release.exe -C config/MFCC12_E_D_A_Z.conf -I ',filePath,... 
'-O ', resultName ];
```